# How to convert row list to column list

Tags: python, numpy

How do you convert `[1, 2, 3]` to `[[1],[2],[3]]` in python?

Also, say I have a vector of length m with values ranging from 1 to 10, I want to create a matrix of size mx10 such that say if vector `y = 1` then the matrix should be `[0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]`. In octave it was possible with,

```
y_train = zeros(m,output_layer_size);
for i=1:output_layer_size
   y_train(find(y==i),i)=1;
end
```

But similar function gives out `VisibleDeprecationWarning` warning in python and does give desired output

```
y_train = np.zeros((y.shape[0],10))
for i in range(10):
    y_train[y==i][i]=1
```

Comment: `[[i] for i in l]`?

Comment: For numpy arrays `arr[None,:]`.

Comment: or `arr.reshape(-1,1)`

Answer (score 1):

Adding a dimenstion to a vector in numpy is easy. You have a number of options available, depending on what you want to do:

1. Use [`np.newaxis`,](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) which is often aliased by `None`, in your index:

   ```
   v = v[:, None]
   ```

   OR

   ```
   v = [None, :]
   ```

   Using `newaxis` allows you to control precisely whether the vector becomes a column or a row.
2. Reshape the vector:

   ```
   v = v.reshape((1, -1))
   ```

   OR

   ```
   v = np.reshape(v, (-1, 1))
   ```

   I have really shown four options here ([`np.reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) vs [`np.ndarray.reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html) and row vs column). Using `-1` in the new vector's dimensions means "whatever size is necessary to make it the same number of elements as the original". It is much easier than explicitly using the shape.
3. Use [`np.expand_dims`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html), which is almost exactly equivalent to `np.newaxis`, but in functional form.
4. Construct a new array with [`ndmin=2`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.array.html):

   ```
   v = np.array(v, copy=False, ndmin=2)
   ```

   This method is the least flexible because it does not let you control the position of the new axis. It is usually used when the only thing that matters is the dimensionality and broadcasting takes care of the rest.

The second part of the question appears to be a simple use-case for fancy indexing in Python. Here is as [IDEOne link](https://ideone.com/h3m4Mq) where I unrolled your octave loop. You can rephrase it in Python as:

```
y_train = np.zeros((y.size, m_output));
y_train[np.arange(y.size), y] = 1
```

Here is an [IDEOne link](https://ideone.com/A225NI) of the demo.

Answer (score 1):

Transposing 1D array directly will not work. It will return the original array. Try this instead:

```
np.atleast_2d(x).T
```

Answer (score -3):

The ones from the comment did not work for me but numpy.where() worked!

    `b=np.array([[0],[0],[2],[2],[4],[1],[6],[7],[5],[9]])
    a=np.random.randint(10,size=(10,10))
    for i in range(10):
        c=np.zeros((1,10))
        c[0][i]=1
        a[np.where(b==i)[0]] = c
    print a`

Comment: You asked two questions.  The comments apply to the first, which is also the subject line.  This answer applies to the 2nd, with the numpy `where` replacing the octave `find`.  It's a good idea to clearly distinguish Python `list` from numpy `array`.  Good solutions when an object is already an array (or needs to be an array) are not the same as optimal list versions.

Comment: I find it curious that in Octave you use `c(i,j)` indexing, but with numpy you use `c[i][j]`.  Why not `c[i,j]`?

Comment: I'm coming from c++ and java where arrays are indexed as `[i][j]` and still learning python so thanks for the new way of indexing. In octave matrix elements are accessed through `( )` but in python through `[ ]` so the difference.